# Как получить доступ к фрагментам

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment

У меня Android Studio 3.6.3. Создал проект на котлине на основе шаблона Navigation Drawer Activity.
В сгенерированный файлах, в content_main.xml есть фрагмент nav_host_fragment, а также в файле mobile_navigation.xml есть такие фрагменты как nav_home, nav_gallery, nav_slideshow. Есть сгенерированные фрагмент классы как HomeFragment, GalleryFragment и т.д. Пункты меню в Navigation Drawer нормально нажимаются, фрагменты меняются в соответствии с меню. Фрагменты наполняю нужной информацией.

Но, проблема в том, что из активити не могу получить доступ к активному фрагменту. supportFragmentManager.fragments возвращает только один фрагмент nav_host_fragment. Этот фрагмент никак не конвертируются через as ни к одному классу фрагментов, таких как HomeFragment, GalleryFragment и т.д.

Например, 
val frag = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
val glr = frag as GalleryFragment - выдает исключение

findFragmentById не находит остальных фрагментов таких как nav_home, nav_gallery, nav_slideshow.

Как получить активный на данный момент фрагмент?
Каким образом создаются экземпляры этих фрагментов, как меняются?

Там, кажется, все управляется посредством этих строк:

```
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow, R.id.nav_tizim), drawerLayout)
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

Но, непонятно как.

Comment: а с какой целью? информацию передать или зачем?

Comment: во фрагменте находится recyclerview, активити реализует интерфейс. функция в активити должна вызвать функцию из фрагмента, чтобы обновить recyclerview. Например, во фрагменте есть кнопка добавляю новый элемент в список. само добавление происходит в функции в активити. после добавление надо во фрагменте запустить адаптер.нотификейшнонченж. или например, нужно прочитать значение переменной во фрагменте из активити

Answer (score 1):

Сложная у вас система честно говоря, нужно смотреть так: список находится в фрагменте, значит итоговые данные нужно передавать из фрагмента, если данные поступают в фрагмент из активности то нужно брать либо bundle либо тоже интерфейс подключать.

Для того чтобы передавать данные из адаптера в активность/фрагмент чаще всего используют интерфейс. Для это создают файл интерфейса и пишут функцию которая необходима для связи с фрагментом, в качестве аргументов используйте данные которые вы хотите передавать:

```
interface AdapterInterface{
    fun myFunction(position: Int....)
}
```

дальше в конструкторе адаптера нужно указать данный интерфейс:

```
class ListAdapter(... private var adaptInterface: AdapterInterface... ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ChatHolder>() {

}
```

в активности при вызове конструктора адаптера нужно писать:

```
listAdapter = ListAdapter(... this@MyFragment)
```

либо если это активность (список должен находится в ней):

```
listAdapter = ListAdapter(... this)
```

после этого фрагмент/активность предложит вам подключить данный интерфейс и переопределить его методы, в итоге у вас в фрагменте будет функция интерфейса `myFunction`. Ну и наконец, 
вызываете в адаптере метод интерфейса и передаете нужные вам данные.

Comment: это я знаю. из фрагмента в активити что угодно могу передавать, через интерфейс. Мое не понимание было то, что в данный момент все изменилось, обновилось в шаблоне Navigation Drawer Activity. Сейчас фрагменты создаются и управляются таким образом:
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow), drawerLayout)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
. Раньше использовался класс ActionBarDrawerToggle